# Can't install the Ubuntu One Indicator

Tags: ubuntu-one

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-ubuntuone
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package indicator-ubuntuone is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'indicator-ubuntuone' has no installation candidate
```

I even tried 'ubuntuone-indicator', but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add [Third-Party Repository](https://launchpad.net/indicator-ubuntuone/) for installing  **UbuntuOne-Indicator**, by following these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rye/ubuntuone-extras
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install indicator-ubuntuone
```

Logout and login to see the Indicator.

**EDIT** : If you have already added the Repository then try changing your mirror from **software sources** *(refer image)* and do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` in terminal , then try installing again

[image]

Comment: I've done already all of this. Sorry if I had not included the sudo add-apt-repository in my example.

Comment: @tonybac -Try changing your mirror from software sources and do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` in terminal , then try installing again.

Comment: It worked. I checked my software sources and found out that the rye ppa was unchecked. I had the ubuntu one indicator working before, but after uninstalling both the Ubuntu One app and the indicator, I also unchecked its ppa from my software sources.

Comment: Fine :) , you provided incomplete info in question then , anyways it is now sorted out, HA :D

Comment: this is not valid anymore under raring

Comment: @papachan - You can update the answer for Raring Ringtail..you are always free to do so.